# Is it possible to implement the document object (or atleast some part of it) on a Worker Script? How?

Tags: javascript, dom, web-worker

So I made a site that calculates how much grinding it would take for a character to get to a certain level. The thing is, I programmed the calculator on the UI script and little did I know that the calculation actually pauses when the user switches tabs.

I did a bit of research and found out about worker scripts. I want to implement the calculation process using workers but the problem is, the code for my calculation relies heavily on the document object, which as we all know, cannnot be accessed by a worker. So the question is, is it possible to implement the document object (or just some part of it) on a worker script?

Is it possible for a worker to have a fake/cloned version of the document object in javascript that would then communicate to the UI script to update/get the property of the UI elements? I don't need everything from the document object, just the important stuff like getting the elements by Id/Name/TagName and getting/setting the value and innerHTML properties. I also need the script to handle events like onclick, oninput, and onload.

Comment: I think that won't be possible within workers.

Comment: Do it the other way around: Build your logic tree, easily shareable between your worker and your DOM, and then decor it with DOM elements.